Can you give an example of a measurable set which is not Borel and whose closure is a null-set?
If $N$ is a measurable set which is not Borel and whose closure is a null-set, then $1_N$ is Riemann-integrable (as it is constant $=0$ and continuous on $\overline{N}^c$ and hence almost everywhere) with integral $=0$ but this function is not Borel measurable but only Lebesgue measurable -- this is the example which it is asked for in Klenke, Exercise 4.3.3.
For the construction of $N$, you can freely assume the existence of a measurable null-set which is not Borel. The point of the question is about how to transition from a measurable null-set which is not Borel to a measurable set which is not Borel and whose closure is a null-set.

This all (what you've written) seems overly abstract and over-the-top for your question, at least for the question you're asking in the title. Just take any non-Borel subset of the Cantor middle thirds set -- hard if you want some kind of explicit description; easy cardinality argument if only pure existence is needed. The closure of the set is a subset of the closure of the Cantor set (monotonicity of the closure operation), which in turn equals the Cantor set (because the Cantor set is a closed set). Hence, the closure of that non-Borel set is a subset of a measure zero set.

easy cardinality argument if only pure existence is needed --- For this, you'll want to use the fact that there are only continuum many Borel subsets of the reals. Maybe this fact is what you're trying to get around by assuming another fact?

I understand this what you have written. I accept it as an answer. The purpose of the abstraction was to avoid an explicit example like the Cantor set. I've no problem with the cardinality argument.

The task of this exercise is just to construct a Riemann integrable function which is not Borel measureable. If you can give an abstract argument as in the question, I will be glad to see it
